# The xml drawable resource file's root tag is <shape>, although, when parsed, always appears of type GradientDrawable, not ShapeDrawable. Why is that?

Tags: android, android-resources

Let's suppose I have the ~/res/drawable/**shape.xml** file defined with `<shape>` as its root tag:

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#0000FF" />
</shape>
```

I want to obtain a `Drawable` instance of this resource in my activity:

```kotlin
val drawable = this@MainActivity.getDrawable(R.drawable.shape)
```

The variable 'drawable' is of type `Drawable`, but I can downcast it to one of `Drawable`'s subclasses. I had expected it to be castable to `ShapeDrawable`, although I got a `ClassCastException` exception. Then I checked to see of what type the variable actually was:

```kotlin
Log.d(TAG, drawable.javaClass.name)
```

Surprisingly, the output was:

> android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable

Why was it designed that way, in Android? Perhaps there's a decent explanation to that, but I can't think of any.

I know that `<gradient>` is one of `<shape>`'s child tags, along with `<stroke>`, `<padding>`, `<corners>`, `<size>` and `<solid>`, but `ShapeDrawable` and `GradientDrawable` are two separate classes, both inheriting from `Drawable`.